# Is there a way to calculate the ground and 10m temperature from standard 2m temperature measurements?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, temperature, measurements

I am wondering if it is possible at all to calculate the ground temperature and air temperature at 10m above ground from 2m measurements, or at least using data that a standard weather station provides.

I am aware it is an oversimplification, but I cannot seem to find any resources concerning the matter. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit 2017/01/11:**

Thank you for your comments, so here is the reason why we are interested in this:

We have noticed that there are often large differences in air temperature between 2m and 10m height, often of 4° to 5°C. I wanted to know if anyone else was interested in this, or are there any models out there which can be used to calculate temperatures at different heights, so a comparison between modelled and real values can be made.

Why is this interesting at all?

It would be great to have a way to know if in a certain area the temperature will not go below 0°C if we have measurements of temperature, humidity and wind at 2m. But, I presume in these days of cheap temperatures sensors and Arduinos, one can always stick a sensor anywere...

Comment: What do you want to use the ground temperature for?  Do you mean surface (skin) temperature or sub-surface?  I'd say it's not going to be possible.  One dataset measuring 2m temperature and three different surface temperatures, as well as six sub-soil temperatures, is at http://www.met.reading.ac.uk/weatherdata/Reading_AWS_weather_report.html .  You could start comparing time series of the four to confirm for yourself that it's not possible.

Comment: @gerrit the link you provided looks really interesting, especially the charts that link from it. Do you know if there is a resource describing the set up a little more, or research results etc?

Comment: @Puffin You can try http://www.met.reading.ac.uk/weatherdata/ and the links from there.  If you live near Reading, UK you can participate in a tour of the observatory.

Comment: Are we having any information on the nature of the substrate - from a core, or from local observation (even at regional area). Also, what is the climate characterizing the area? I think an answer would be of a better quality knowing these, if you could update your question.

Comment: @D-Vida - I think I can answer, but I need to know, because as it is written I may interpret the wrong way: so you have a sensor at 2 m underground. And you want to model what temperature you could have at z=10 m deep underground right? And at ground surface too (z=0 m) ? I am asking because Air Temperature, Ground surface temperature and underground at X depth are three different things.

Comment: @Etienne Godin Oh, I was refering to air temperatures at heights _above_ ground: 0m (on the ground), 2m and 10m. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Answer (score 3):

There is an equation for a model of vertical variation in air temperature

[image]

It unifies concepts from a whole range of sciences. You will need to know the sensible heat flux *H* from the respective surface (which can be calculated as a result of the energy balance of where you are). Further you can calculate the volumetric specific heat capacity *pc(p)* of air, which is approximately *1.2 kJ/(m³ K)* and relate it to the shear velocity or friction velocity of your surface. This is finally related to the logarithmic measure of the term *(z-d)/zH* where *z* is the height of which you want to know the temperature and *d* is the zero plane displacement. *zH* finally is the Roughness of your surface.

This has to do with the fact, that heat transfer over surfaces usually is turbulent and not just determined by vertical convection. I recommend you to take a look at Campbell & Norman "An Introduction to Environmental Biophysics" (1998). It's a very comprehensive book and treats all the mentioned concepts.

I'm working on a basic computation of this at the moment but it still needs a little time. Once it's done, I'd be very excited to see if it actually is able to model the measured temperatures. I'll keep you updated on how it's going.